# Automorphism Group of a Space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, covering-spaces, automorphism-group

I am considering the following situation:
[image]

Let us call the space on the left $Y$ and the space on the right $X$.

The group of deck transformations is defined as
$\operatorname{Aut}(Y/_X):=\{φ:Y→Y∣φ\text{ a homeomorphism s.t. }p∘φ=p\}$.

In this example, $\operatorname{Aut}(Y/_X):=\{\operatorname{Id}\}$. Could someone explain why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A homeomorphism $\varphi\colon Y\to Y$ sends loop to loop, and arc to arc. If we impose $p\circ \varphi=p$ on $\varphi$, it means that $\varphi$ can be restricted on each fiber, i.e., for $x\in X$ and $y\in p^{-1}(x)$ the $\varphi$ sends $y$ to another point of $p^{-1}(x)$. Therefore, a deck transformation sends a $B$ loop of $Y$ to a $B$ loop of $Y$. But there is only one $B$ loop in $Y$. So, $\varphi$ sends the $B$ loop to itself.

Comment: Also, $\varphi$ sends a vertex (black bold dot) of $Y$ to a vertex of $Y$. Combining all these, $\varphi$ sends the vertex of $B$ loop to itself. Now, uniqueness of lifting says that $\varphi=\text{id}$.

Comment: As mentioned in the film "A Beautiful Mind", there are similarities between this situation, where $\varphi$ must be the identity, and the fact that any field automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3] 2]$ must also be the identity.

Comment: @User Thank you so much! The uniqueness of path lifting helped!